# Is there a way to stack a custom rendered bar within each category so they don't overlap

Tags: echarts, grouped-bar-chart

I have rangebar to visualize date ranges of items within a certain category. The issue is that the bars overlap and I would like them to stack.

I tried creating separate series for each issue but it has the same effect as creating one series for all the data.[range bar overlapping bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKIzX.png)

Answer (score 0):

The [stack property](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.stack) of the bar chart might help with your problem.